# Open up terminal/shell on remote server via tcp request

Tags: node.js, bash, http

I have this:

```
const http = require('http');
const cp = require('child_process');

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {

  const bash = cp.spawn('bash');
  req.pipe(bash.stdin, {end:false);
  bash.stdout.pipe(res);
  bash.stderr.pipe(res);

});

server.listen('4004');
```

when I hit the server with:

```
curl localhost:4004
```

and I type bash commands, nothing gets outputed to my console, anybody know why?

**Note**: To address security I plan to run this in a docker container, use https/ssl, and implement authentication (any recommendations on auth schemes lmk).

**More importantly**, I am looking for *shell prompts* to appear ... apparently bash by itself doesn't open up a shell/prompt?

Comment: One way to get a terminal experience would be to use ssh, but I am trying to figure out how to do it without ssh, using some other terminal program or something

Answer (score 0):

*This is a partial answer, but I started a bounty because I am looking for something better.* I was able to create something rudimentary with TCP like so:

```
const net = require('net');   // !use net package not http
const cp = require('child_process');

const server = net.createServer(s => {

  const bash = cp.spawn('bash');
  s.pipe(bash.stdin, {end:false});
  bash.stdout.pipe(s);
  bash.stderr.pipe(s);


});

server.listen('4004');
```

not sure why it won't work with HTTP though. I connect to it using netcat:

```
nc localhost 4004
```

but this isn't opening a terminal, just a bash process. the experience is not ideal, as described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519364/bash-shell-modes-how-to-pipe-request-to-shell-on-remote-server

however I am looking to replicate the shell experience you have when you do something like:

```
docker exec -ti <container> /bin/bash
```

when I run *my* script it "works", but I *don't* get any **shell prompts** or anything like that. (One way to solve this might be with ssh, but I am trying to figure out a different way).

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an http server with telnet. It depends on how you're starting the http server. Here's an example

Start an http server with the npm package http-server

```
npm install -g http-server 
cd ~/ <Any directory>
http-server
```

Now seperately start a telnet session

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

OR

```
nc localhost 8080
```

And then type something like GET /

Use the telnet client instead of nc

Check this: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/telnet-http11/
Update: Running an ssh server over nodejs. It allows you to run an ssh server 
I found this at https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var inspect = require('util').inspect;

var ssh2 = require('ssh2');
var utils = ssh2.utils;

var allowedUser = Buffer.from('foo');
var allowedPassword = Buffer.from('bar');
var allowedPubKey = utils.parseKey(fs.readFileSync('foo.pub'));

new ssh2.Server({
  hostKeys: [fs.readFileSync('host.key')]
}, function(client) {
  console.log('Client connected!');

  client.on('authentication', function(ctx) {
    var user = Buffer.from(ctx.username);
    if (user.length !== allowedUser.length
        || !crypto.timingSafeEqual(user, allowedUser)) {
      return ctx.reject();
    }

    switch (ctx.method) {
      case 'password':
        var password = Buffer.from(ctx.password);
        if (password.length !== allowedPassword.length
            || !crypto.timingSafeEqual(password, allowedPassword)) {
          return ctx.reject();
        }
        break;
      case 'publickey':
        var allowedPubSSHKey = allowedPubKey.getPublicSSH();
        if (ctx.key.algo !== allowedPubKey.type
            || ctx.key.data.length !== allowedPubSSHKey.length
            || !crypto.timingSafeEqual(ctx.key.data, allowedPubSSHKey)
            || (ctx.signature && !allowedPubKey.verify(ctx.blob, ctx.signature))) {
          return ctx.reject();
        }
        break;
      default:
        return ctx.reject();
    }

    ctx.accept();
  }).on('ready', function() {
    console.log('Client authenticated!');

    client.on('session', function(accept, reject) {
      var session = accept();
      session.once('exec', function(accept, reject, info) {
        console.log('Client wants to execute: ' + inspect(info.command));
        var stream = accept();
        stream.stderr.write('Oh no, the dreaded errors!\n');
        stream.write('Just kidding about the errors!\n');
        stream.exit(0);
        stream.end();
      });
    });
  }).on('end', function() {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });
}).listen(0, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + this.address().port);
});
```

Comment: I want to open a *terminal* on the remote machine, like ssh, this won't do that tmk...I will make the question a little bit clearer.

Comment: You can't open a terminal (ssh) since ssh requires a continuous bi-directional connection. HTTP will only entertain one Request and will send one response. That's how http servers work.

Comment: yes that's why my partial answer has tcp not http, you're right

Comment: if you start a tcp server, you can have it react to the commands you send whichever way you want. HTTP will not entertain that. One request, one response. Unless you use keep-alive

Comment: yeah try my tcp code out, you will see what  I mean, it works, but it doesn't open a terminal, just bash

Comment: Okay. That's more of an application thing. SSH is an application layer over the network. Data is constantly exchanged over the server and client. You just don't see it. You'd have to implement all of that using tcp. Or you can use https://www.xnite.me/programming/2018/01/15/nodejs-ssh-server-example.html

Comment: If you want to build one yourself, you'll have to implement a client that transfers data on each keystroke. And the server will send data in some other format (json maybe) and client will interpret this and show something similar to how a shell would work. Its quite a bit of work, but can be done

Comment: well I figure maybe install a terminal program and when the terminal opens it just runs bash? there must be some terminal program I can install and then I can execute that?

Comment: @MrCholo I gave you two URLs that provide exactly that.

Comment: @AhmedMasud he wants to create a program that can act as a terminal (ssh) server. The ones you shared are connecting to ssh over the browser, they don't implement ssh servers

Comment: @MrCholo I found something in javscript you might want to look at

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee *sigh* he never mentioned ssh and he is not saying he want's to create an SSH in original question, even in the comment he is confusing ssh with a tty.  a TERMINAL ≠ ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this "over the web" so to speak. However, your approach will not work, because you are mixing paradigms (batch vs. interactive), and you are missing large chunks of setup that's needed to run terminal applications.

Normally I would show you how to program this, however, that's really involved. Have a look at:

https://github.com/chjj/tty.js

and,

https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js

as starting points to create your solution.

Both are usable directly from node.js to serve up terminal applications over HTTP.

Answer (score -2):

Your approaches are quite mixed, nonetheless, when ever you finally connect to the remote server do not use 'bash' as a method to start the connection, BASH is just born again shell with other commands & stuff in it,

Rather use some of the following program, command-line names: i.e :

```
 ~ $ 'gnome-terminal'     

 ~ $ 'xterm'
```

there you will now be referencing a true program in the system, even kernel level C code has its own recognition of these, if not changed.